# В localStorage нужен массив объектов, но не получается прикрутить key к объекту

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localstorage

Не могу понять как добавить key/value в массив. Надо чтобы в localStorage был массив объектов, но не получается прикрутить id к объекту book.
Помогите пожалуйста!

```
import UUIDv4 from 'uuid/v4';

function addBook(authorBook, nameBook, yearBook, imageSRC) {
  const id = UUIDv4();

  let book = {
    author: authorBook,
    name: nameBook,
    year: yearBook,
    imageSRC: imageSRC
  };

  let books = [];
  let key = id;
  books.unshift({
    key: book
  });


  let parseBook = JSON.stringify(books);

  return localStorage.setItem('SAVED_BOOK', parseBook);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для хранения данных в формате `key => value` в javascript есть тип данных `Map`. 
Подробная документация [по использованию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Using_the_Map_object).

Если вам необходима полная поддержка браузерами то посмотрите на решение ниже, для итерации по объекту вы можете изучить [этот комментарий](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379304/7678419).

Так же обратите внимание на `localStorage.getItem('SAVED_BOOK')`, если вы хотите сохранять несколько книг то для начала вам нужно получить значение из `localStorage`

```
import UUIDv4 from 'uuid/v4';

function addBook(authorBook, nameBook, yearBook, imageSRC) {
  const id = UUIDv4();
  let books = localStorage.getItem('SAVED_BOOK');

  if (!books) {
    books = {};
  } else {
    books = JSON.parse(books);
  }

  books[id] = {
    author: authorBook,
    name: nameBook,
    year: yearBook,
    imageSRC: imageSRC
  };

  let parseBook = JSON.stringify(books);
  return localStorage.setItem('SAVED_BOOK', parseBook);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы в объект вместо свойства с именем `key`, добавилось поле со значением переменной `key` можно воспользоваться [нотацией для вычисляемых свойств](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_ECMAScript_2015)

```
books.unshift({[key]:book});
```